# AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have just started with using custom user model. and after running make migrations and migrate , I am getting this error: **AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'**

here is my account/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('user',)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and here in TaskList/models.py I am trying to use user as Foreign key:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from Account.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ToDoList(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description  = models.TextField(help_text='Explain your task!', blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    due_date     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    completed    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Author       = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in my settings.py I have added :
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Account.UserProfile'`

Comment: Show us the full stack trace

Comment: Read the [docs on customising the user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) again. Your `UserProfile` model is completely wrong. Are you trying to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or are you substituting with a custom user model?

Comment: @gogaz sorry but how am i supposed to do this?

Comment: @dirkgroten my major objective was to display the current logged in user for which i was following 3rd option in this link  https://wsvincent.com/django-referencing-the-user-model/

Comment: I understand but your `UserProfile` isn’t a User model (it’s just a regular Model connected to User) so you don’t have a custom user model and therefore shouldn’t set AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: @dirkgroten Thankyou this article helped !!